# How to update swing components text to differert locale after run-time

Tags: java, swing, localization, resourcebundle

I would like to enable my program to use multiple languages with the ResourceBundle class. Here is my code:

Main.java

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.util.Locale;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JLabel label0 = new JLabel(Language.getString("Main.label0"));
        JLabel label1 = new JLabel(Language.getString("Main.label1"));
        //...
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.add(label0);
        frame.add(label1);
        //...
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Language.setLocale(new Locale("de_DE"));
        label0.setText(Language.getString("Main.label0"));
        label1.setText(Language.getString("Main.label1"));
        //...
        frame.pack();
    }
}
```

Language.java

```
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.MissingResourceException;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Language {
    private static final String BUNDLE_NAME = "Language";
    private static Locale locale = new Locale("en_US");
    private static ResourceBundle RESOURCE_BUNDLE = ResourceBundle
            .getBundle(BUNDLE_NAME, locale);

    private Language() {
    }

    public static String getString(String key) {
        try {
            return RESOURCE_BUNDLE.getString(key);
        } catch (MissingResourceException e) {
            return '!' + key + '!';
        }
    }

    public static void setLocale(Locale locale) {
        Language.locale = locale;
        Language.RESOURCE_BUNDLE = ResourceBundle.getBundle(BUNDLE_NAME, locale);
    }
}
```

Language_en_US.properties

```
#Language English
Main.label0=This is some text
Main.label1=This is some more text
```

Language_de_DE.properties

```
#Language German
Main.label0=Dies ist ein Text
Main.label1=Dies ist etwas mehr Text
```

As you can see, in `Main.java`, I must manually set all the text of the labels again. This would be easy with 5 or 10 of them but if I am using 50 of them plus tooltips, tab names, combo boxes and menus all needing to change there locale, it gets pretty impractical to do this for all of them. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm no expert on this subject, but from things I've seen, it appears that resource bundles are the way to go, and so if I were in your shoes, that's where I'd start. Tutorials can be found easily via Google: [Resource Bundle Examples](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=java%20resource%20bundle%20example). A better question would be asked **after** reading a number of tutorials and examples. Then you could be much more specific including asking just what about them that you don't understand, or ask about why your code isn't working.

Comment: Based on the example [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html), it seems that you just have a method that returns the text for the key. What is special about using a ResorceBundle then?

Comment: Added bunches of more details!!!

Answer (score 2):

The idea behind resource bundles is to actually "externalize" all the strings in your application, so that you can then write different files with different strings (let's only talk about strings now) for different languages, without touching the source code.

For example, suppose you have :

```
System.out.println("Sorry, an error has occurred");
```

You can use a PropertyResourceBundle like this :

```
System.out.println(bundle.getString("error_occurred"));
```

And then create files like :

```
error_occurred=Sorry, an error has occurred
```

Or

```
error_occurred=Purtroppo si è verificato un errore
```

Then, you load the right properties into the resource bundle based on the language the user selected or the locale of the platform :

```
public void initBundle(String language) throws IOException {
  InputStream is = Class.getResourceAsStream("/bundles/messages_" + language + ".properties);
  try {
    return new PropertyResourceBundle(is);
  } finally {
    fis.close();
  }      
}
```

Comment: Can you give me an example for a language please?